# R C5.0 tree model to list conversion

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart

I am using the C5.0 decision tree in R from the C50 package.

The training function C5.0 returns a list which also contains a "tree" element which is basically a text representation of the tree. I am wondering if there are existing ways to convert that (text tree) into a R data structure, e.g. a list or a graph. The purpose is to use it for further analysis e.g. identifying assignment nodes and not only the class.

If there are no existing packages/functions that can do this then I will consider writing my own.

I found the following blog entry that converts the text tree into graphviz but not really the same thing.

http://r-project-thanos.blogspot.de/2014/09/plot-c50-decision-trees-in-r.html

Thanks

Comment: Max (Kuhn, the `C50` maintainer) and I once talked about that it would be nice if there was an `as.party()` method for `C5.0` objects. This should be possible and the `partykit` provides similar code for `rpart` and `J48` (from `RWeka`). This enables unified printing, plotting, predictions, etc. However, so far we haven't tried to write a suitable parser for `C5.0`. If you do, please let us (`partykit` maintainers) know.

Comment: @AchimZeileis thanks for quick reply and introducing me to partykit. I will be happy to use RWeka and partykit, though I am not sure how to use it. I tried but couldn't get it working, here is CV question for it: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192433/j48-partykit-access-flat-list

Comment: There is nothing wrong with wanting to use C5.0 rather then C4.5 (via J4.8) as it contains some improvements and avoids some of the shortcomings of the old algorithm. (Personally, I use neither but typically unbiased recursive partitioning algorithms like `ctree`...but I'm partial to that, of course).

Comment: Follow-up: Digging a bit deeper into `C50` it turns out that Max Kuhn has actually done this work and there is an `as.party()` method for `C5.0` objects...it is just not (yet?) exported. But you can still call it if you reach into the NAMESPACE. For an example, run `example(plot.C5.0)` and then `p1 <- C50:::as.party.C5.0(mod1)`. The result is a `party` object for which you can do `plot(p1)` or `print(p1)` or all the other things that `partykit` supports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We haven't updated the package yet but there is an updated version of `as.party` for C5 trees that has been checked in. You can install it with the `devtools`package via

```
devtools::install_github("topepo/C5.0/pkg/C50")
```

You can use the function [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618490/get-decision-tree-rule-path-pattern-for-every-row-of-predicted-dataset-for-rpart) to get the rules:

```
> model <- C5.0(Species ~ ., data = iris)
> modParty <- C50:::as.party.C5.0(model)
> pathpred(modParty)[c(1, 51, 101), ]
      response prob.setosa prob.versicolor prob.virginica 
1       setosa  1.00000000      0.00000000     0.00000000
51  versicolor  0.00000000      0.97916667     0.02083333
101  virginica  0.00000000      0.02173913     0.97826087
                                                             rule
1                                             Petal.Length <= 1.9
51  Petal.Length > 1.9 & Petal.Width <= 1.7 & Petal.Length <= 4.9
101                        Petal.Length > 1.9 & Petal.Width > 1.7
```